# Retraining a Model from 3 Channels (RGB) to 4 Channels (RGBA), can I use the 3 channel weights?

Tags: python, pytorch, rgba

I need to expand a model from RGB to RGBA. I can handle the code rewrite on the model, but instead of retraining the entire model from scratch, I would love to start it off with it's 3 channel weights + zeros.

Is there an easy way to change torch's save of 3 channel weights into 4?

Comment: The answer depends on the specific model you are planning to use, can you provide more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do a little bit of "model surgery". Assuming the input to the model is only processed directly by a convolutional layer then you can just replace that conv layer with another that has `in_channels` set to `4`. Then you can set weights to zero and copy over the old weights (and biases if applicable) from the original conv layer.

For example, say we had a simple model that looked like this

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 10, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 5, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(125, 1)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        return self.linear(x.flatten(start_dim=1))

model = SimpleModel()
```

Supposing that the model is trained at this point, we could perform the surgery as follows

```py
y_rgb = torch.randn(1, 3, 5, 5)

# get performance on initial z_rgb
z_rgb = model(y_rgb)

# perform model surgery
with torch.no_grad():
    new_conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 10, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=True)
    new_conv1.weight.zero_()
    new_conv1.weight[:,:3,...]=model.conv1.weight
    new_conv1.bias.copy_(model.conv1.bias)
    model.conv1 = new_conv1

# add a random alpha channel to y_rgba
y_alpha = torch.randn(1,1,5,5)
y_rgba = torch.cat([y_rgb, y_alpha], dim=1)

# get results on rgba model
z_rgba = model(y_rgba)

# compare z_rgb and z_rgba, print mean-square difference
z_err = ((z_rgba-z_rgb)**2).mean().item()
print('Err:', z_err)

# save results to a new file
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'checkpoint_rgba.pt')
```

which should give you an error of zero or very close to zero.

Of course if you don't have a `bias` term in your first conv layer then you don't need to copy that over.

Assuming you've saved the new state dictionary, then you will probably want to update the model class definition so that your input convolution layer takes 4 channel input instead of 3. Then next time you can directly load the new state dictionary without additional steps.

---

Now it's not strictly necessary to do the surgery on the model directly. Though I tend to prefer it as I find it easier to verify correctness.

Assuming you saved off the state dictionary for the RGB model, you could also just directly modify the state dictionary.

```py
# assuming you saved RGB model using torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'checkpoint_rgb.pt')
state_dict = torch.load('checkpoint_rgb.pt')
old_weight = state_dict['conv1.weight']
state_dict['conv1.weight'] = torch.zeros(
    old_weight.shape[0],
    old_weight.shape[1]+1,
    old_weight.shape[2],
    old_weight.shape[3]
).type_as(old_weight)
state_dict['conv1.weight'][:,:3,...] = old_weight
torch.save(state_dict, 'checkpoint_rgba.pt')
```

Comment: Interestingly (at least for me) your suggestion on setting zero weights to newly introduced connections is OK. 
Intuitively I thought it should be random, because zeros will not allow to break symmetry. But I rechecked math and found that as soon as input is different from image to image, other weights of the kernel are different from zeros, than we are getting different outputs of the kernel and we will have different gradients  for different connections and kernels.

So I see not reason now why not to use zeros.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer! After some thought, I ended up starting from scratch for a 4 channel. Since I'm dealing with RGBA images quite often, I'm going to try out your solution later when I rewrite the SOTA model I'm working with.